# Do app.module providers and components share the same instance of an Injectable?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, injectable, angular2-providers, ng-modules

When I add the injectable CameraChannelService into ngModule's provider array:

```
import { CameraChannelService } from './camera-channel.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BabylonWallpaperDirective,
    MenuComponent,
    WorksComponent,
    LabsComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    ActionBtnComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [
    CameraChannelService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**Does it create a new instance for just that component? when I inject it into one of the NgModules declarations components?**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CameraChannelService} from '../camera-channel.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-works',
  templateUrl: './works.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./works.component.scss'],
  providers: [CameraChannelService]
})
export class WorksComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cameraChannel: CameraChannelService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.cameraChannel);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes...**

If you add **`providers: [CameraChannelService]`** to Component's **`@Component decorator`**, it ***creates a new instance scoped to that component only***.

If you declare **`providers: [CameraChannelService]`** in **`@NgModule`** that ***creates an instance scoped to entire application***.

So if you want to use *same instance* throughout application then only *declare service in **`@NgModule decorator`*** of **`AppModule.ts`** file and don't declare it again in **`Component's @Component decorator`**

---

**Side Note** : Rather than declaring service to **`@NgModule`**,use **[CoreModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-module)** to declare service and import it into **`AppModule`**. So, later if you want to configure your service, you will be able to configure your service.